# A proof of the simple pressing down lemma, is sup $x=x?$

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to practice working with ordinals, of which I have only a rudimentary knowledge. The simple pressing down lemma says that if $f:\omega_1\to \omega_1$ satisfies $f(x)<x\ \forall x\in \omega_1,\ $ then $f$ is constant on some unbounded set. The proof is by contradiction, and after being given copious hints, I think I understand the proof, except for the last step:

$1).$ If $g(t)=\sup f^{-1}(t)$ then it follows that $g(t)>t.$

$2).$ Define a sequence in $\omega_1$ by setting $x_0=0,$ and in general $x_{n+1}=\sup\left \{ g(t):t\le x_n \right \}.$

$3).\ x=:\sup \left \{ x_n \right \}$ exists because $\left \{ x_n \right \}$ is countable.

$4).$ The above shows that $x_n< g(x_n)\le g(x_{n+1})$ and now since $f(x)<x$ there is an integer $j$ and an $x_j$ such that $f(x)<x_j$ for otherwise, $f(x)$ would be an upper bound for $\left \{ x_n \right \}.$

$5).$ Then, it follows that $g(f(x))\in \left \{ g(t):t\le x_j \right \}$ so $g(f(x))\le x_{j+1}.$

The next step is where I am not sure if the argument is correct. Can you comment, or provide a more rigorous proof?

$6).$ On the other hand, $1).$ shows that $g(f(x))=\sup x$ and $4).$ implies that $x$ is not a successor ordinal, so $\sup x=\bigcup x=x,$ and we have $x\le x_{j+1}<x_{j+2}$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't see why $x_n < g(x_n)$: If $x_n \not \in f[\omega_1]$, then $g(x_n) =\sup f^{-1}\{x_n\} = \sup \emptyset = 0$ and I don't see why $x_n \in f[\omega_1]$ is guaranteed.

Comment: @StefanMesken: but $f(0)\neq 0$ because  $f(x)<x$ and so $g(0)\neq 0$ either, right?

Comment: I don't see how $1$ is true ... If $f^{-1}(t) = \emptyset$, $g(t) = 0<t$

Comment: @Max How can $f^{-1}(t) = \emptyset?$ Because then $f(0)=t\ge 0$ which can't happen because $f(t)<t$ by assumption

Comment: @Driver8 $f^{-1} \{t\} = \emptyset$ if and only if there is no ordinal $y$ such that $f(y) = t$. You seem to confuse $\emptyset$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$ here.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is not the inverse bijection of $f$, because that wold not exist. $f^{-1}$ is the preimage function; as Stefan Mesken explains.

Comment: Yes,  I see. Thank you.

Comment: @ Stefan Mesken: this is a basic question I have about functions defined on ordinals. $\omega_1$ is a collection of transitive sets, which are themselves the "points" on which $f$ is defined, but then how can $f:\omega_1\to \omega_1$ satisfy $f(x)<x?$ Where would $f$ map the least element $0=\emptyset$ to? Or does $f(x)<x$ mean that $f$ maps the elements of the $set$, $x=\left \{ \alpha\in x \right \}$ into itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your attempt... Here is an alternative proof (which I guess is close to what you had in mind).

Suppose $f$ is not constant on an unbounded set. In other words, for all $y \in \omega_1$
$$
f^{-1} \{y\} = \{x \in \omega_1 \mid f(x) = y \}
$$
is bounded. Recursively construct a sequence $(x_n \mid n \le \omega)$ as follows

- $x_0 = \omega$,
- $x_{n +1} = x_n \oplus \min \{  x \in \omega_{1} \setminus \{0\} \mid \forall y \ge x \colon f(y) > x_n \} \ $ and
- $x_{\omega} = \sup_{n < \omega} x_n$.

Note that this is well-defined: $f^{-1} \{ z \mid z \le x_n \}$ is a countable union of bounded subsets of $\omega_1$ and hence bounded. Therefore there is some $x$ such that for all $y \ge x \colon f(y) > x_n$.

Also note that $(x_n \mid n < \omega)$ strictly increasing.

Now consider $f(x_{\omega})$. We have $f(x_{\omega}) < x_{\omega}$ and since $x_{\omega} = \sup_{n < \omega} x_n$ there is thus some $n < \omega$ such that $f(x_{\omega}) < x_n$. But $x_{n+1} < x_\omega$ and hence -- by definition of $x_{n+1}$ -- $f(x_{\omega}) > x_n$. Contradiction!

---

$\oplus$ denotes ordinal addition.

Comment: You can alter the defintion of $x_{n+1}$ (and $x_0$) without affecting the proof. The only thing I care about is that $(x_n \mid n \le \omega)$ is strictly increasing and that, for all $n < \omega$ and all $y \ge x_{n+1}$, $f(y) > x_n$.

Comment: Could you explain why $f^{-1} \{ z \mid z \le x_n \}$ is a countable union of bounded sets?

Comment: @Driver8 $f^{-1} \{ z \mid z \le x_n \} = \bigcup_{z \le x_n } f^{-1} \{ z \}$. The $f^{-1}\{z\}$ are bounded by our assumption and $x_n$ is countable since $x_n < \omega_1$.

Comment: I forgot the original assumption! Ugh. Now I get it. Thank you.

Comment: @Driver8 You're welcome. Am I right that this is close to the proof you had in mind?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to build an increasing sequence, assuming for a contradiction, that $g(t)=\sup f^{-1}(t)$ exists for each $t\in \omega_1$, whose $\sup$ would end up less than some $x_k$,because of the hypothesis that $f(x)<x.$ I got confused, as you pointed out, between looking at the ordinals as "points" and also as sets.

Comment: @Driver8 'I got confused [..]' that can happen very easily in set theory -- where every function is a set function and subsets of the (co)domain can be elements as well and vice versa... That's where being consistent about your notation becomes important.